# Rcpp isn't finding Boost headers

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

I have a file called `src/windows.cpp` (windowing functions for vectors, nothing to do with MS Windows!) in an R package project.  The top of the file looks like this:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>

using namespace Rcpp;
```

That doesn't seem to be enough to let it find the Boost headers - when I do a `devtools::load_all(.)` to trigger compilation, I see this build failure:

```
* installing *source* package ‘MyPackage’ ...
** libs
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" 
-I/usr/local/include  -std=c++11 -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
-fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c windows.cpp -o windows.o
windows.cpp:6:43: fatal error: boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
                                           ^
compilation terminated.
```

I've got `BH` installed, and the relevant headers are present:

```
> .libPaths()[1]
[1] "/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4"

> dir(file.path(.libPaths()[1], 'BH/include/boost/algorithm/string'))
 [1] "case_conv.hpp"             "classification.hpp"        "compare.hpp"              
 [4] "concept.hpp"               "config.hpp"                "constants.hpp"            
 [7] "detail"                    "erase.hpp"                 "find_format.hpp"          
[10] "find_iterator.hpp"         "find.hpp"                  "finder.hpp"               
[13] "formatter.hpp"             "iter_find.hpp"             "join.hpp"                 
[16] "predicate_facade.hpp"      "predicate.hpp"             "regex_find_format.hpp"    
[19] "regex.hpp"                 "replace.hpp"               "sequence_traits.hpp"      
[22] "split.hpp"                 "std"                       "std_containers_traits.hpp"
[25] "trim_all.hpp"              "trim.hpp"                  "yes_no_type.hpp"
```

It looks like the core problem is that the `[[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]` directive isn't adding the relevant Boost directory to the compiler directives, right?  What should I look for in my setup that might be causing this?

I've added `BH` to the `Imports:` section of my `DESCRIPTION` file, is that correct/advisable?

Comment: You are confusing usage by _Rcpp Attributes_ within a session (which parses and uses `[[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]`) which what a _package_ does where we rely on standard R infrastructure.  Hence `LinkingTo:` as per the answer below, and of course as clearly delineated in _Writing R Extensions_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added it to `LinkingTo` as mentioned [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/bh.html)?

[Further](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-attributes.pdf),

> Note that while the `Rcpp::depends` attribute establishes dependencies
>   for `sourceCpp`, it’s important to note that if you include the same
>   source file in an R package these dependencies must still be listed in
>   the `Imports` and/or `LinkingTo` fields of the package `DESCRIPTION` file.
>   ...
>   Packages that provide only C++ header files (and no shared library) need only be referred to using `LinkingTo`.

Comment: Correct.  See my comment above.

Comment: Oh!  Thanks.  Confusing, since we're not actually linking to anything, this is a header-only dependency and just adds a `-I` flag to the compiler (not linker) invocation.  It does clearly say that in the docs, I just didn't grok that "LinkingTo" applies to situations other than linking.